# How To Make A Default Text Display For This Script?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script to display the current date to someone, but I want to do two things to it.

First, I want to change the format to MM/DD/YY, so it's only showing the year in 2 digits.

Then second, how can I add a default? So if it's not able to be pulled by someone, it will show "Today" instead of a date?

Here's the script if anyone could help:

```
 var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
```

Comment: try this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/k58Yz/)**</kbd>

Add a div to your HTML and put your default text inside it:

```
<div id="date">Today</div>
```

Then with javascript, change it, and if the user don't have javascript, it remains not changed:

```
// create date
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = month + "/" + day + "/" + (year + '').substring(2);

// now insert it
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
```

- `[!]` Don't forget to add the JS after your element or add it to document ready.

Comment: what should i call the js file? i treid to do this and called the JS file date.js, but it didn't show anything. don't i have to add write somewhere within a <script> tag within that div to make it work?

Comment: i added <script src="date.js"></script> to my header.. but still this is not working..

Comment: Write them in a file like `date.js` and put `<script src="date.js"></script>` before `</body>` tag.

Comment: @sab You must add it before the `</body>` tag to ensure that your `id="date"` element is exists.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason for this to fail, If javascript is enabled in the client it should work, still if you want error handling

```
try {
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
    document.write(month + "/" + day + "/" + (year + '').substring(2))
}catch(e){
    document.write('Today');
}
```

Comment: what is the catch(e) ? i am putting this directly into my html wrapped in a <script> </script>

Comment: im thinking it might fail because it will be for people with cell phones so im not sure 100% if it will work for them

Comment: @sab if javascript is available in the mobile browser it should work, the `try...catch` is an error handling mechanism

Comment: thanks aron. i tried to add catch(e) underneath the .substring(2)), however, I got an error on the catch(e) line. is there someway to seperate this or what is the proper context when i'm putting this directly into the html using <scrpit> </script>?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last two digits of day by doing `String(year).substring(2,4)`. So you end up with:

```
console.log(day+"/"+month+"/"+String(year).substring(2,4));
```

To set defaults you can use the following:

```
var demo = value1 || default
```

You can play around with these ideas [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/cQfhF/)

Comment: where would i add the substring(3,4) ?

Comment: you changed teh javascript around?